# Can javascript submission of a form interfere with previous axios calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal, axios

I have an intermittent problem my users experience, but I can not cause it to happen, so I've never experienced it myself.

I have a vue.js component with two html forms. The user fills out the first form, submits it... a function is called which does two axios calls, and then programatically submits the second form. The second form is a standard PayPal form that sends the user off to PayPal. See the code snippets below.

The doLogging() function writes to a file on another server. The doMail() function sends email and also writes to a different file.

The user is always sent on to the PayPal site, and never notices any problems. However, sometimes both the logging and emails happen, and sometimes neither happen. It is always either both or neither. It is as if the axios calls happen sometimes, but not others.

Here are the html snippets:

```
<form @submit.prevent="processRegistration()">
  <button type="submit"
    class="button is-info">Ready to pay with PayPal
  </button>
  ... other form elements ...
</form>

<form id="paypalForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" class="hidden">
   ... paypal form elements ...
   <input type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal"/>
</form>
```

And here's the stripped down functions that are called:

```
 processRegistration() {
    this.doLogging();
    this.doMail();

    let paypalForm = document.getElementById('paypalForm');
    paypalForm.submit();
 }

async doLogging() {   // log info to a file
  let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};
  try {
    await axios.post('https://logging.xxx.com/logger.php', this.stuff, {headers: headers});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}, 


async doMail() {  / send email and log info to a file
    let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};
    try {
        await axios.post('/email.log.php', this.otherStuff, {headers: headers});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
 },
```

Comment: That's because sometimes your `doLogging()` and `doMail()` are finished before your user gets redirected to paypal, and sometimes not.

Comment: I thought that by using `await` that they would all execute serially. @Frank

Comment: Yea, but processRegistration is not an async function.

Answer (score 0):

The promise in `doLogging()` and `doMail()` is likely not resolved by the time the paypal form is submitted. The most obvious way to resolve this is to await both function (and make `processRegistration()` async).

```
async processRegistration() {
    await this.doLogging();
    await this.doMail();

    let paypalForm = document.getElementById('paypalForm');
    paypalForm.submit();
 }
```

Now, `doMail()` will wait for `doLogging()` and `paypalForm.submit()` won't be called before `doMail()` is resolved. Another option would be to use chaining.

This is not the most beautiful approach but get's the job done anyways.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot more about Promises, here's my solution to my own problem. Since the doLogging() and doMail() posts can happen concurrently, using a Promise.all() seems to be the thing to use to assure that those posts are complete before the post to PayPal happens.

```
doLogging() {
 let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};
 return axios.post('https://logging.xxx.com/logger.php', this.stuff, {headers: headers});
},

doMail() {
 let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};
 return axios.post('/email.php', this.otherStuff, {headers: headers});
},

submitToPayPal() {
 let paypalForm = document.getElementById('paypalForm');
 paypalForm.submit();
},

processMembership() {
 let log = this.doLogging();
 let mail = this.doMailToDancer();

 Promise.all([log, mail])
  .then(this.submitToPayPal())
  .catch(error => {
   console.log(error.message)
  });
},`
```

Comment: `Promise.all([log, mail])
  .then(this.submitToPayPal())` executes `this.submitToPayPal()` right away, before the promises resolve, so your problem remains. You need to make it into `.then(() => this.submitToPayPal())` or `.then(this.submitToPayPal)`.

Comment: OK, great. I think I now see the difference. I have to keep clear about `submitToPayPal()` and `submitToPayPal` and what `.then` needs.